# Linear Regression on non-stationary regressor

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity, linear

I am doing a linear regression and the regressors, like GDP, inflation, etc, (independent variables) are non-stationary.

What should I do if those regressors are not stationary?  Should I 'make' it to stationary before regression?